# js function does not exist?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Using MVC...

```
 <a onclick="confirmDeactivate(@mobileDevice.Id, '@mobileDevice.IsActive');" class="show-pointer"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
```

So Id, and boolean will be passed to confirmDeactivate...

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

         function confirmDeactivate(mobileDeviceId, mobileDeviceIsActive) {
            var i =1;
        }
    </script>
```

It is telling me confirmDeactivate is undefined.
what am i doing wrong?

**EDIT**
inspect element:
[image]

Comment: have you inspected the html?

Comment: It's seem that the problem is in passed parameters. If the parameters are remove then function works fine.

Comment: Are you sure the script that defines the function resides in the same document as the element (and not, say, in a nested `<iframe>`)?

Comment: If I put static values as parameters works fine, http://jsfiddle.net/W646X/

Comment: In which case do you know that @mobileDevice has a value for the two items you are passing in?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the script where you have your function is loaded before you try to call it. If it is an external file, Make sure you load that in your HEAD section/ Top of your razor view.

OR you can try an [unobutrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) approach

I updated the markup a little bit, Added a css class name and some data attributes.

```
<a class="show-pointer clicky" data-deviceid="@mobileDevice.Id"
             data-active="@mobileDevice.IsActive"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
```

and in your javscript, Bind a click event to your anchor tag and wrap it inside your [document ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

```
<script>
 $(function(){

   $("a.clicky").click(function(e){

     e.preventDefault();
     var _this=$(this);
     var deviceId=_this.data("deviceid");
     var isActive=_this.data("active");
     alert(deviceId+", " +isActive);
     //do something with the values now
   });

 });    
</script>
```